# Apply border radius to last row of a table (with ng-repeat)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I use this to style the top row (header) of my table, but how would I do the same for the LAST row?

UPDATE: I am using AngularJS ng-repeat on the table and the middle rows are using the styling intended for the last row only.

```
th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}
th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Is something like this what you want?

```
tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
}
tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}
```

Comment: You are close. The issue here is that all the 'middle' rows still receive the styling.

Comment: @Michael_B 's answer runs it for you and it looks like it works

Answer (score 1):

```css
th,td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}
th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}
tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
}
tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Very Nice.  With code like yours, my page still styles each middle row though. Do you think my issue is between AngularJS and CSS selectors ?

Comment: Open up the browser inspector and see what styles are being applied to your middle rows. You'll be able to see the source of those style, as well.

Comment: Ah yes. middle elements have tr:last-child td:first-child styling.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
tr:last-child { 
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have a `table` with the `id` of `foo`.

```
#foo tr:last td:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}
#foo tr:last td:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}
```

Make sure you have no invisible `tr`s at the end of the table.